# Print preview and print only prints a portion of my web page

Tags: html, css, printing, print-preview

I have a rather large table data I need to print, but when I go to `Print Preview` or `Print`, I only see what's currently visible on the page, and not the entire content of the web page.

This happens in all browser. What could be causing this?

Comment: This sounds strange. Any chance of a live link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange, never heard of this happening. My speculation would be that you have some HTML construct in place like a container `div` with `overflow: auto`  that makes the table actually span inside an element that is as tall as the viewport, instead of the whole page.

Comment: Wouldn't that give scrollbars on the table? The whole table is visible, but only some of it prints.

Comment: @Stefan not necessarily, the scrollbars could be those of the `div`.

Comment: I've clicked through all the containers down to the bottom table, and Firebug lists the computed style as visible, not overflow.

Comment: My search was not thorough. >_>

Comment: Yes, it was. `overflow: auto;` had been added to fix some spacing issue (this was a bad fix), and it broke print-preview, which one of our users needed for business functionality :/.

Answer (score 7):

Oh my god, I spent so much time on it...

I wanted to use puppeteer to generate a pdf and I didn't understand why it only printed the first page in the output pdf.

Here was the reason: **I had set properties overflow: auto and height: 100% on tag <body>. Once I've removed it, it worked fine.**

I hope it can help someone.